# Unable to locate the 'Edit' link by using any type of locators in the below snippet

Tags: selenium, xpath, webdriver

I tried almost every type of locators like xpath, CSS, linktext etc. Please see below snippet:

```html
<td class="actionColumn">
<a class="actionLink" title="Edit - Record 1 - Sarika Mahurkar" onmousedown="searchResultClick.mousedown(this, event)" data-seclkr="1" data-seclkp="/50011000008fykL/e" data-seclki="50011000008fykL" data-seclkh="afd7fe8d662a1ff5858a5a5ca316d1ff" data-seclke="Case" href="javascript:srcUp(%27%2F50011000008fykL%2Fe%3FsrPos%3D0%26srKp%3D500%26retURL%3D%252F_ui%252Fsearch%252Fui%252FUnifiedSearchResults%253FsearchType%253D2%2526str%253D02518285%2526isdtp%253Dvw%2526isWsVw%253Dtrue%2526nonce%253D3c705d75cbfb6776b726b3a59cf3e9aa83e1ac47fe50b2b8b3c47adff9e3484a%2526sfdcIFrameOrigin%253Dhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fadidas--rfcuat.cs18.my.salesforce.com%2526initialViewMode%253Dsummary%2526asPhrase%253D1%2526searchOwner%253D0%2526saveOptions%253D1%26isdtp%3Dvw%27);">Edit</a>
</td>
```

`

Edit

Comment: Try `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='actionLink'")).click();`

Answer (score 0):

xPath based on **Edit** word in title of action

```
//td[@class='actionColumn']/a[contains(@title, 'Edit')]
```

Also you can add condition that a element has actionLink as a class

```
//td[@class='actionColumn']/a[contains(@title, 'Edit') and @class='actionLink']
```

Comment: Or try locating the text by:
//td[@class='actionColumn']/a[text()='Edit']